# Yii2 AssetBundle publishOptions pattern syntax?

Tags: yii2, assets

Might be stupid, but just wanted to ask if the syntax I'm using is correct when publishing asset's files. [The Guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html) instructs to use folder names without trailing asterisk, however for me it does not work that way.

The weird thing is even if I specify to only publish css and images folder, the assetManager also publishes other folders in `$sourcePath` (luckily without files inside). What's more, when new files are added to images folder, they remain unpublished until I delete `@web/assets` folder. Is this to be expected?

```
<?php
namespace app\views\layouts\main\assets;
use yii\web\AssetBundle;

class ThemeAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $sourcePath = '@theme';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        'css/site.css',
    ];

    public $publishOptions = [
        "only" => [
            "css/*",
            "images/*",
        ],
        "forceCopy" => false,
    ];
}
```

Comment: Last question...they become unpublished...that's because the force copy parameter value is false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first note that you should set `$sourcePath` or `$baseUrl` not both of them (If you set the both, the former overwrites the last when `assetManager` calls `publish` method).

> The weird thing is even if I specify to only publish css and images
>   folder, the assetManager also publishes other folders in $sourcePath
>   (luckily without files inside).

If you wanna avoid asset manager to publish this folders, you must mention them on `except` parameter of `publisOptions`:

```
'except' => [
    "doc/",
    "img/",
],
```

> What's more, when new files are added to images folder, they remain
>   unpublished until I delete @web/assets folder. Is this to be expected?

Yes! It's a natural behavior. You may set `forceCopy` property of `publishOptions` to `true` in development mode. This causes to update asset contents in each refresh. Easily you can use Yii production constant: `YII_DEBUG`.

```
public $publishOptions = [
    'only' => [
        'js/',
        'css/',
    ],
    'forceCopy' => YII_DEBUG,
];
```

So totally you have an asset manager like this:

```
<?php
namespace app\views\layouts\main\assets;
use yii\web\AssetBundle;

class ThemeAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $sourcePath = '@theme';

    public $css = [
        'css/site.css',
    ];

    public $publishOptions = [
        "only" => [
            "css/*",
            "images/*",
        ],
        'except' => [
            "doc/",
            "img/",
        ],
        "forceCopy" => YII_DEBUG,
    ];
}
```

Comment: do you know how the only and except works with *.less files? I want the less file to be converted but not copied. But when i add 'only' => 'css/*.css' the less file isn't converted. If I add 'except' => '*.less' the conversion is also not done...

Comment: Actually now I don't have any idea about your problem and also free time for reading the source of `AssetBundle` for finding a solution. I suggest you to post a new question. @BHoft